# Proof that $\alpha$ is constructible $\iff$ there exists a finite tower of degree two extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I guess my question is the Title. 
I have been wondering how to prove that, knowing that my intuition comes from the : 
*You can build your number from the rationals, by taking finite roots, adding, substracting...*

But how does the actual, field theoretical argument go ?

Comment: For the [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number#Transformation_into_algebra), one does not take arbitrary finite roots, one takes only square roots.

Comment: In fact, that's where the "degree two extensions" come in. Fields are closed under adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing, so no extension is needed for those operations. By using the quadratic formula, a root of every degree 2 polynomial can be attached by taking an appropriate degree two extension, i.e. by attaching the square root of the discriminant of that polynomial.

Comment: The proof is found in many Abstract Algebra books. Check Dummit & Foote or Aluffi for example. The complete proof isn't difficult but a bit long to reproduce here.